# Binding Complex Class object into datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

We have two class and there is relation with many to one company and product. So when we display product then we show the product name with company, so there is any direct way to bind `DataGridvView`.

```
public class Product : Common 
{
    public Int32 ProductID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductType ProductOfType { get; set; }

    public virtual Company ProductCompany { get; set; }

    public virtual PackageType ProductPackageType { get; set; }
}
```

`DGProduct.DataSource = db.Product.toList()`, so when we bind the `DataGridvView` then its show `MedicineEntity.ProductCompany` as rows, so there is any way to direct binding or need to bind manually using loop. Please some one suggest if any option is available, otherwise need to bind `DataGridvView` using loop or convert list into datatable.

Comment: [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-objects-to-windows-forms-datagridview-controls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to define `ToString` method on `Company` class.

```
class Company
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Others methods involves manually specifying columns in `DataGridView`

One approach involves writing custom [TypeDescriptionProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and decorating `Company` class with `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute`. Use this article for full code: [How to bind a DataGridView column to a second-level property of a data source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msdnts/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source/)

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(CompanyDescriptionProvider))]
class Company
{
    // ...
}
class CompanyDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    // implementation
}
```

Another is to define `BoundField` and add it to your grid:

```
public class CompanyField : BoundField
{
    protected override string FormatDataValue(object dataValue, bool encode)
    {
        var obj = dataValue as Company;

        if (obj != null)
        {
            return obj.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.FormatDataValue(dataValue, encode);
        }
    }
}
```